# How properly write function to filter content in a template for plugin "multiple content blocks"

Tags: filters

In a website I'm building (using my own designed theme, for a business site that doesn't have a blog, IOW, using WP for it's CMS), I have 5 templates: the homepage, the 404 page, the default (page.php), a small one-column and a large one-column. I use the default template for 6 pages in the site. That template is 2-column with a wide main column and narrower right column. But each page will have different content in the right column - mostly text - so it's really not a "sidebar" situation. I want to use the plugin "Multiple Content Blocks".

I used it in the homepage template and it's easy and works beautifully, but all I had to do was place this code:

```
<?php the_block('blockname'); ?>
```

in the template in my "colR" div. In actual fact the code is:

```
<?php the_block('News'); ?>
```

as I named the block "News".

So far so good.

In the readme.txt it has the following FAQ:  How do I filter the content?, and it says:

"Use the function get_the_block instead of the_block, like this:
 `<?php $content_to_edit = get_the_block('blockname'); ?>` and you can now edit this variable with PHP."

I'm ASSUMING (perhaps incorrectly) that this means I can write a function or filter for the plugin -- what I want to be able to do is name a block for each of the six pages, and then in the page.php template, be able to specify "if this page, use this block" but I don't know how to write it.

So, for example, if one of the pages is called "customer", or ID 21, and I want to name the content block "contact", what exactly goes in the `$content_to_edit` part? I've tried a couple things but they haven't worked.

Also, would it need to go inside the loop? In my page.php I have the loop above the colR (for column right) div.

Help greatly appreciated!

Comment: I was misunderstanding how the plugin worked. One block accepts different content from different pages - only need one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misunderstood how the plugin worked. I can use one "block" call in a template and it shows different content from different pages. Do NOT need a different block for every page. MY BAD.